# Window Cordova throwing System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime...'

Tags: c#, cordova, visual-studio-2017, winrt-component

I created one sample cordova app using windows platform and added one test plugin , while calling native code through test plugin. I'm getting exception

WinRTError: The text associated with this error code could not be found.

System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime, Version=4.0.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=..'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
at WindowImageAnnotation.ImageAnnotationPlugin.CreateImageAnnotation(String jsonString)
at module.exports.coolMethod (ms-appx-web://../www/plugins/cordova-plugin-imagewindow/src/windows/WindowImageProxy.js:25:11)

**App Version:** [image]

**Native code version:**
[image]

This line throwing exception inside plugin, method is present in that variable "ev"

[image]

[image]

**Exception:**
[image]

**Native code:**
[image]

I changed the version also and tried but getting every time same exception. Any solution about this.
Will provide if anything required.
Thanks in Advance

**Running App in Visual Studio Community 2017 15.9.30**

Comment: does adding the package fixes it? https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime/4.0.11

Comment: HOORAY.. Thanks @magicandre1981. that works, I installed  version 4.0.10.0 from nuget, because in cordova App build folder have "4.0.11.0" version. So I changed native package to same version.